# Real Analysis, Folland Proposition 2.22 Integration of Complex Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Proposition 2.22 - If $f\in L^1$, then $|\int f|\leq \int |f|$

Attempted proof - If $f$ if a real-valued function then $$\left|\int f\right| = \left|\int f^+ - f^-\right|\leq \int f^+ + \int f^- = \int |f|$$
If $f$ is complex valued, then $$\left|\int f\right| = \left|\int Re f + Im f\right| \leq \left|\int Re f\right| + \left|\int Im f\right| \leq 2\int |f|$$
Since $2$ is just a scalar we are done.

I am not sure if this is right any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Proposition 2.22 - If $f\in L^1$, then $|\int f|\leq \int |f|$

**Proof**:

**1.** Note that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a, b>0$ then $|a-b|\leq a+b$.
So, if $f$ if a real-valued function then 
$$\left|\int f\right| = \left|\int f^+ - f^-\right|=\left|\int f^+ - \int f^-\right|\leq \int f^+ + \int f^- = \int (f^+ +  f^-)= \int |f|$$

**2.** If $f$ is complex valued, if $\int f =0$ the result is trivial.
Suppose $\int f \neq 0$, then $\int f = \left | \int f \right |e^{i \theta}$. So $$\left|\int f\right| = e^{-i\theta}\int f=\int e^{-i\theta} f$$
In particular, $\int e^{-i\theta} f$ is real, so we have 
$$\left|\int f\right| = \textrm{Re}\int e^{-i\theta} f= \int \textrm{Re}( e^{-i\theta} f)\leq \int | \textrm{Re}( e^{-i\theta} f)|\leq  \int |  e^{-i\theta} f|=\int |f|$$

Note that we used item 1.) in the step
$$ \int \textrm{Re}( e^{-i\theta} f)\leq \int | \textrm{Re}( e^{-i\theta} f)|$$